# Pagination gives 404 in template

Tags: pagination, 404-error, pods-framework

I have a page in '*Pages*' called '*News*'. This page has a template containing my paged custom `WP_Query`.

Here's the code:

```
<?php

    $paged = 1;
    if (get_query_var('paged')) {
      $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    } elseif (get_query_var('page')) {
      $paged = get_query_var('page');
    }

    $arguments = array (
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'post_type' => 'fltnews',
        'paged' => $paged,
        'meta_key' => 'publish_date',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value',
        'order' => 'DESC'
    );

    $custom_wp_query = new WP_Query($arguments);
    $temp_wp_query  = $wp_query;
    $wp_query       = NULL;
    $wp_query       = $custom_wp_query;

    echo "<ul class='content-list'>";
    if ($custom_wp_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($custom_wp_query->have_posts()) : $custom_wp_query->the_post();
            echo "<li class='content-list-item'>";
            $podsForNewsItem = pods('fltnews', $post->ID);
            $podsImage = pods_image ( $podsForNewsItem->display( 'thumbnail_picture'), 'full');
            if ($podsImage != ""){
                $podsImage = "<div class='content-list-thumbnail-picture'>" . $podsImage . "</div>";
            }

            printf("<a href='%s' class='item-container'>%s
                            <div class='content-list-body'>
                                <div class='content-list-publisher'>
                                    <div class='date-block'><span class='date'>%s</span></div>
                                </div>
                                <div class='content-list-title'>%s</div>
                                <div class='content-list-text'>%s</div>
                                <div class='content-list-link'>Les mer</div>
                            </div>
                        </a>",
                    esc_url(get_permalink($post->ID)),
                    $podsImage,
                    getDateAsNorwegian($podsForNewsItem->field('publish_date')),
                    $post->post_title,
                    $post->post_excerpt);

            echo "</li>";
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_postdata();

        previous_posts_link('Nyere &raquo;');
        next_posts_link('&laquo; Eldre nyheter', $custom_wp_query->max_num_pages);

        $wp_query = NULL;
        $wp_query = $temp_wp_query;

    endif;
    echo "</ul>";
?>
```

I've looked at the following questions and answers:

- [How to fix pagination for custom loops?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/120407/how-to-fix-pagination-for-custom-loops)
- [Pagination gives 404 error](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60855/pagination-gives-404-error)

It seems like everyone always fixes the 404 problem when adding the '*paged*' key and value to the `WP_Query`. However, this doesn't work for me.

The page '*News*' is at the following URL: /news.
The `next_posts_link` gives the following link: /news/page/2.

This is the one giving me the 404.
My Permalink Settings is as follows: Day and name.

I don't understand why I'm getting the 404.

Comment: I wonder why you don't use custom post type archive and chose to implement it withing a page template?

Comment: This 'custom post type' called 'fltnews' is created through pods. Is this why this doesn't work? Also, I think creating a custom post type would solve this. So my question is now: how can I fix this when using pods?

Comment: _That_ question might be better aimed at Pods' developers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did what Rarst told me to do. First I searched around in the [Pods Framework documentation](http://pods.io/docs/code/pods/pagination/). This solved my problem.

Here's what the code looks like right now.

```
<?php

  $params = array(
    'orderby' => 'publish_date.meta_value DESC',
    'limit' => 10
  );

  $fltNewsPods = pods( 'fltnews', $params );
  while ($fltNewsPods->fetch()) {
    echo "<li class='content-list-item'>";
    $podsForNewsItem = pods('fltnews', $fltNewsPods->display( 'id' ));
    $podsImage = pods_image ( $podsForNewsItem->display( 'thumbnail_picture'), 'full');
    if ($podsImage != ""){
        $podsImage = "<div class='content-list-thumbnail-picture'>" . $podsImage . "</div>";
    }

    printf("<a href='%s' class='item-container'>%s
                          <div class='content-list-body'>
                              <div class='content-list-publisher'>
                                  <div class='date-block'><span class='date'>%s</span></div>
                              </div>
                              <div class='content-list-title'>%s</div>
                              <div class='content-list-text'>%s</div>
                              <div class='content-list-link'>Les mer</div>
                          </div>
                      </a>",
                  esc_url(get_permalink($podsForNewsItem->display( 'id' ))),
                  $podsImage,
                  getDateAsNorwegian($podsForNewsItem->field('publish_date')),
                  $podsForNewsItem->display( 'title' ),
                  $podsForNewsItem->display( 'excerpt' ));
      echo "</li>";
  }

  echo $fltNewsPods->pagination( array(
    'type' => 'paginate',
    'prev_next' => false,
    'first_last' => false
    ) );

  echo "</ul>";
?>
```

It's basically the same, although high use of the pods framework.

I guess this didn't work with the WP_Query version because this wasn't a custom post type, so it wasn't using the Wordpress Framework. Wordpress wouldn't know how these should be paginated.

Comment: what happen if you test over limit of your paging? normally it should be 404.

Comment: I can test this and give you back the results. You are correct in that it should give a 404.

Comment: I mean "normally" if it is still in your custom page template, base on your question, you get 404 page in pagination. By default WP if you use page or custom page template, tested pagination with /page/2, it doesn't create 404 error actually.